# NextPeer Multiplayer Android Game Not Connecting

Tags: android, libgdx, multiplayer, viber, nextpeer

I have a game on Google Play that utilizes NextPeer for realtime multiplayer. I know that they were acquired by Viber, but I saw a message on their site a while back that they would continue supporting existing games using their service. Is this not the case? My game now has an error that says "OH NO! You appear to be offline. Please check your network and try again." Is my multiplayer just dead now, or is Viber continuing to run the server messaging? Can any NextPeer multiplayer users chime in with advice? What is the best viable alternative? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately the Nextpeer service has been discontinued as of October 2016 (as you can tell by the website - https://www.nextpeer.com/). As an alternative we have advised our developers to use other services.